# Why are the following classes are not found

Tags: .net, saxon, ikvm

This is a case of using saxon9ee.jar in a .net app using IKVM (we compile separately because we use a different IKVM).

I run set to drop me in the debugger on any exception as I follow the practice of no exceptions in the happy path.

Saxon is throwing ClassNotFoundException for the following classes, but it runs fine:

- com.saxonica.ee.domino.DominoNode
- com.saxonica.xsltextn.style.SaxonElementFactory
- com.saxonica.ee.extfn.js.IXSLElementFactory

Is this a problem or is it expected?

**update:** Ok, it's definitely a problem with the class loader (IKVM). And the answer is [IKVM Class Loader](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/ClassLoader/).

Comment: The main developer behind IKVM announced the end of the project last April, http://weblog.ikvm.net/ So you probably should think twice if this is the approach you want to use.

Comment: @LexLi - we've started supporting it (one optimization). It's too useful to let it go away.

Comment: That's great! But if you do have started you should make some more noise to notify the community :) A GitHub organizationo/repo and so on would be a better signal to revive it and regain the attention.

Comment: @LexLi - already done - https://github.com/wwrd/ikvm & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615183/which-approach-is-best-for-creating-postscript-in-c/50633588#50633588 I also emailed the ikvm developers email list about a month ago.

Comment: Since you do have a repo, I will write my opinions there instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

`com.saxonica.ee.domino.DominoNode` -- I find the exception a little surprising here. If your build includes the `com.saxonica.ee.domino` package then I would expect the dynamic loading of this class to succeed; if it doesn't then I would expect that dynamic loading isn't attempted. The dynamic load is initiated by a call on `Configuration.registerExternalObjectModel()`.

`com.saxonica.xsltextn.style.SaxonElementFactory`, `com.saxonica.ee.extfn.js.IXSLElementFactory` -- similarly for these two, as far as I can see dynamic loading will only be attempted in cases where the classes actually exist.

So I think what we're seeing here is a situation where the class is present, but dynamic loading of the class is failing. This suggests some kind of problem with the class loading environment, and as a first step it's probably worth investigating why the class loading failure occurs.

It's quite possible for Saxon to operate without these "plug-in" classes, so the fact that they aren't being loaded probably is no problem for your application, but it does suggest to me a potential problem with the class loading environment that may have other more serious symptoms as well.

Comment: It's definitely the class loader - fails to load our classes too when I try that. Any brilliant ideas on what to do in IKVM to get this working? thanks

Comment: Could you write up more specifically what you did, so perhaps we can use the information to help other users?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the class loader could not find the class - even though the call and the desired class are in the same DLL (remember this is IKVM so DLL, not JAR).

The cause of this, and the solution, [are described in this blog entry](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/ClassLoader/).

We solved it by adding the following call when our code first initializes. This code is in the same DLL as all of the Saxon code (we create a single DLL of all of our code and all the 3rd party JARs).

```
// use misspelled addBootClassPathAssemby 
ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssemby(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ());
```